# Creando api en node obtengo error: bodyparse is not defined

Tags: nodejs

Estoy creando una API en node pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));  
        ^
ReferenceError: bodyParser is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/keily/code/node-api-rest-example/app.js:7:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Este es mi app.js:

```
var express  = require("express"),  
    app      = express(),
    http     = require("http"),
    server   = http.createServer(app),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));  
app.use(bodyParser.json());  
app.use(methodOverride());

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {  
   res.send("Hello World!");
});

app.use(router);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/tvshows', function(err, res) {  
  if(err) {
    console.log('ERROR: connecting to Database. ' + err);
  }
  app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Node server running on http://localhost:3000");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node es javascript y en javascript todas las variables deben ser declaradas eso incluye a los módulos de tu aplicación. [`bodyParser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) es un módulo como cualquier otro así que debes declararlo con `var` y cargar el módulo con [require](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules). El mismo error te da una pista porque es de tipo [ReferenceError](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError)

> El objeto ReferenceError representa un error cuando se hace referencia a una variable que no existe.

Para solucionarlo escribe:

```
var express    = require("express"),  
    app        = express(),
    http       = require("http"),
    server     = http.createServer(app),
    // ya tienes un identificador llamado bodyParser y en el cargas el módulo
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    mongoose   = require('mongoose');
```

Ten en cuenta que el módulo que intentas cargar lo instalas con `npm` usualmente con un comando

```
npm install body-parser
```

por lo que este se encuentra en la carpeta `node_modules` y por lo tanto la llamada de require solo necesita el nombre del módulo

```
var variable = require('modulo')
```

Si fueras a cargar un fichero que tu mismo hayas escrito tienes que usar una ruta relativa para [indicarle a node donde buscar](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)

```
var variable = require('./myCodigo')
```

En ninguno de los dos casos debes especificar extensión ya que el Node [asume por defecto](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules) la extensión `js`, `json` y `node` en ese orden.

Por último recuerda que estos módulos no tienen nada de especial, son simples objetos exportados usando `module.exports` así que puedes hacer algo como:

```
console.log(bodyParser)
```

y mirar los métodos que vienen incluidos.